# How to base64 encode a SHA256 hex character string

Tags: python, base64, encode, sha256

Hi I need help to get a base64 encoded column, what I got is a sha256 hashed column, I suppose to get 44 characters, but when I try this in python

`[base64.b64encode(x.encode('utf-8')).decode() for x in xxx['yyy']]`

it returns 88 character, anyone can help with this? Basically I want to achieve the steps showing in the pictures below in Python, thanks!
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you "suppose to get 44 characters"? Please provide a concrete example that shows an example of something you put in, something you get out and explain what you expected to get out.

Comment: I'm confused with what you are trying to do. When I run your code each item in the list has 4 characters in it, and the number of items in the list depends on how many characters are in `xxx['yyy']`. I don't see where I'm suppose to be seeing 44 or 88 characters.

Comment: @Grismar, I am not familiar with encoding. So I have an sha256 hashed email column which is 64 character, I use a base64 encoding tool online, I got 44 characters, but I have the entire column to encode, trying to figure out the Python code to do so..

Comment: @hostingutitities.com sorry for the confusion. the xxx is suppose a table name, yyy is an sha256 hashed email column which is 64 characters, but I need to encode it to 44 characters using base64 encode..

Comment: Base64 will *never* make a string smaller, it will always make it larger.

Comment: @MarkRansom you're correct, but for novice programmers that may appear not to be true in cases like `b64encode('a\tb\tc\n'.encode())` - it's easy to forget that `\n` is only a single character long, even if your OS may typically encode it as two bytes, and `\t` is always a single character. The `len()` of `\t\n` is 2, but is often mistaken to be 3 or 4.

Comment: @Grismar it's not the encoding step that converts `\n` to `\r\n`, that's a separate part of file I/O.

Comment: I know - hence 'mistaken to be'. String representation, characters, byte encodings and text file newline conventions are entirely separate things, but easy to confuse in Python, as they are presented on the CLI and when printed in very similar fashion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The step in the first image consist of a few substeps:

- a text is entered, but that is just the character representation of a UTF-8 encoding
- sha256 hashing is applied to that bytes string
- the resulting digest byte sequence is rendered in its hexadecimal representation

So:

```
from hashlib import sha256

s = 'user@example.com'

h = sha256()
h.update(s.encode('utf-8'))  # specifying encoding, optional as this is the default
hex_string = h.digest().hex()
print(hex_string)
```

The second image seems to suggest it takes that hex representation as text again, and base64 encodes it - but really it takes the byte string represented by the hex string and encodes that.

So, starting with the hex string:

- decode the hex to bytes (reconstructing the digest bytes)
- encode the bytes using base64 into an ascii bytes string
- decode that resulting bytes string into characters for printing

```
from base64 import b64encode

digest_again = bytes.fromhex(hex_string)
b64bytes = b64encode(digest_again)
# no real need to specify 'ascii', the relevant code points overlap with UTF-8:
result = b64bytes.decode('ascii')
print(result)
```

Put together:

```
from hashlib import sha256
from base64 import b64encode

s = 'user@example.com'

h = sha256()
h.update(s.encode())
print(h.digest().hex())

b64bytes = b64encode(h.digest())
print(b64bytes.decode())
```

Output:

```
b4c9a289323b21a01c3e940f150eb9b8c542587f1abfd8f0e1cc1ffc5e475514
tMmiiTI7IaAcPpQPFQ65uMVCWH8av9jw4cwf/F5HVRQ=
```

Why your code didn't work:

```
base64.b64encode('user@example.com'.encode('utf-8')).decode()  # superfluous utf-8
```

This:

- encodes the characters 'user@example.com' into bytes using UTF-8
- encodes that byte string using base64
- decodes the resulting byte string into a character string

Nowhere does it apply SHA256 hashing, nor does it create a hex representation, if you were expecting that. The end result doesn't match because it is the text representation of the base64 encoding of the original text's UTF-8 encoding, not the digest of its SHA256 hash.

Or perhaps I misunderstood and you already had the hex encoding, but you're putting that in as a string:

```
x = 'b4c9a289323b21a01c3e940f150eb9b8c542587f1abfd8f0e1cc1ffc5e475514'
base64.b64encode(x.encode()).decode()
```

That does indeed result in a 88 character base64 encoding, because you're not encoding the bytes, you're encoding the hex representation. That would have to be this instead:

```
x = 'b4c9a289323b21a01c3e940f150eb9b8c542587f1abfd8f0e1cc1ffc5e475514'
base64.b64encode(bytes.fromhex(x)).decode()
```

... and perhaps that is the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34995/why-do-we-use-hex-output-for-hash-functions) on the Cryptography Stack Exchange discusses why you're getting 64 characters. Basically, for historical reasons hashes are typically hex encoded even though this results in 64 characters while a base64 encoded hash would only be 44 characters. But if you need it base64 encoded there is a way of doing it. The following will give you a base64 encoded hash

```
from base64 import b64encode
from hashlib import sha256

email = 'user@example.com'
email_as_bytes = email.encode('utf-8')
hash_as_bytes = b64encode(sha256(email_as_bytes).digest())
hash = hash_as_bytes.decode('utf-8')
```

Since b64encode and sha256 both operate on bytes, we can chain them together, and the resulting code isn't too terrible.

Comment: Note that OP was getting 88 instead of 44 characters, not 64 (as a result of encoding the hex encoding, instead of encoding the original byte sequence, which is indeed twice the length)